# How many password combinations are possible with 6 lower case letters in Python

Tags: python

Simple question. Just learning programming. As the title states, what is the calculation to find the amount of possible password combinations. 6 lower case English letters, considering with 1 letter there are 26 possible combinations, with 2 letters it's 26 * 26. Need the simple { print() } function to give me the output. I have tried `print((26*26)*4)` as well as `print((26 * 26) * 5)`

Again I am a newbie so I am trying to solve the problem on one of my tests. Thank you in advance for help with this simple matter.

Comment: `print(26**6)` maybe ?

Comment: It's not a question of just learning programming. Where or when is `2626` equivalent to multiply 26 times 26 instead of being equivalent to `(2 X 1000) + (6 X 100) + (2 X 10) + 6)`?

Comment: This is totally unrelated to python, it is pure math. If you wanted to know "how to formulate ... formula in python", e.g. in scipy, then it would be a good question. Your question is about the formula itself, and yes the answer is it is 6th power of 26, 26^6 or pythonic way 26**6. But that's in any basic tutorial you can find anywhere.

Comment: Well I was told to ask the community if I had any questions and yes I already figured it out, and it is just simple math. But still appreciate the time for commenting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say the question is very clear, but if the question is just the title then the answer is simple:

`26^6` or in python syntax `26**6`

If you want a print statement it would be `print(26**6)`

More generally: The amount of combinations for X characters where any character has N combinations is `N^X`

Do note that this is only true when using exactly that amount of characters in every combination

Answer (score 0):

The format of the answer is bad and also wrong place to ask , but anyway since you tagged python I provide a python code :

```
# Provide in this variable the password length you want to compute possible combinations
# Let it be 5
password_length = 5

print(pow(26,password_length))
```

Comment: A more complex way of writing that but I appreciate the response, will save this for the future when I will be writing more difficult scripts. Thanks!